# Proper way to test Android apps

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

Is there a utility / service / way to properly test Android apps since there are currently 18 active screen resolutions and 9 OS versions.

So far I can test on 1 device with 480x800 resolution and OS version 4.4.x
As a second device I want to get 1080x1920 resolution and OS version 4.2.x

Without having a proper device can I check compatibility with OS version 5.x.x and of course all other display resolutions?

Comment: What about emulators?

Answer (score 2):

With the [Genymotion Emulator](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) you can test your apps with a huge amount of versions and screen resolutions, phones, tablets...

Answer (score 1):

I think if there existed such a thing for `native android apps` we all knew about it.

There exists such a thing, but not for native apps, it is for `Xamarin` developers(`C#`). More info [here](http://xamarin.com/test-cloud)

All you can do(`Android Studio`) is that:

**1**.Choose one layout

**2**.Go to Design page of it

**3**.In the Left corner you have a button like this:

[image]

**4**.You can choose to:

-Preview All Screens Sizes

-Preview Android Versions

-others...

This is a static testing method but is better than nothing. Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow that did actually look promising until I saw pricing starts at 1000$ per month

Comment: It is a very powerfull and big testing software in cloud, but the price is big too. I dont know for sure if there is any discount for students. I know for sure that you cand get thier IDE, Xamarin Studio for free if you are student, but know nothing about the testing.

Comment: Imagine how many resources do you need to emulate 10 or 100 devices, not to say 1000. That's why the price is very high.

Comment: I didn't say the price is not reasonable. It is just out of question for many developers

Comment: I hope that in a few years Android will introduce something like this at a resonable price. Right now testing is the biggest problem for android developers.

Comment: I see no other answer to this post. If you think I helped you to get an idea of how is it going on with my answer, give it a Up Vote. I need it being a new user in this community. Thanks in advance!